# Export source from subversion repository

Tags: svn, xcode4

In Xcode 3.x there was an option to Export the source-code (Subversion repository) on to your local machine. This used to be a local copy, not tied to the online repository.

I don't see this option in Xcode 4. Is this feature missing?

Comment: I believe it's missing, I can't see the option anywhere, but I've only been using Xcode 4.1 for about a week.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it's missing, I can't see the option anywhere, but I've only been using Xcode 4.1 for about a week. – DonnaLea

Answer (score 0):

By drag and drop, you will be prompt if you want to export a repo **or** do a checkout. Hope this help someone.